# TDD scala tutorial

Tags: scala, tdd

I am working with scala for couple on months.
I want to focus on functional programming using scala . I am looking for a book that shows real world application using scala . and preferred (if there is one) with TDD approach
books that I read are concept and syntax , now I want to dive in FP programming using scala with TDD approach and looking for a good tutorial using real world applications as a reference . 
any recommendations ?

Comment: You are unlikely to find a book dedicated to TDD in Scala just yet - I'd recommend choosing a good TDD in Java book - e.g. "Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided By Tests" by Freeman and Pryce

Comment: @DNA Thanks , but I really trying to get a real good practice on functional programming . if there is no book yet, maybe someone wrote a tutorial ... or there is a book draft... just asking...maybe I'll get lucky

Comment: Hum it's confusing. Are you trying to learn TDD or functional programming? @DNA is right: TDD is language agnostic, you want find something targeting scala specifically. For functional programming, you can find many books on this topic.

Comment: @vptheron there are TDD books that language oriented such as Professional-Test-Driven-Development-with-C-Developing-Real-World-Applications-with-TDD of worx . I asking if there is such book that is functional programming oriented

Comment: @igx but such books usually just use the language as a vector to convey more general ideas and practices. TDD has nothing to do with functional programming, it's applicable to any programming paradigm.

Comment: @vptheron , thank you , that helps me to be more accurate - I want to focus on functional programming using scala . I am looking for a book that shows real world application using scala . and preffered if there is one, with TDD approach

Answer (score 4):

For functional programming with Scala, here are a few suggestions:

- http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed
- http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/
- http://www.manning.com/raychaudhuri/ (this one mention TDD in a couple of chapters)

Answer (score 3):

Just found this book [testing in scala](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022602.do?intcmp=il-code-books-testing-in-scala-code-podcast) which is close to what I was looking for